# Input element with multiple types?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form and there is an input field where I want the user to either upload a file from their computer OR type a URL.

Is it possible to have an input field that has multiple types? In my case BOTH text and file?

I am also using AngluarJS and Bootstrap if that makes it easier.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that would double up like that, but check this out: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21930/whats-the-least-confusing-ui-for-offering-to-either-enter-a-url-or-upload-a-fil

Comment: well not going to happen with modern file inputs since most will not let you type into the textbox anymore. You will need to supply two options.

Comment: This would allow for file upload injections, no browser would support text and file type.